# Changing the argument number in a macro in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, idapython

Can I change argument number to macro in IDA pro Hex-rays?

```
 fd = open("a", 513, 0644);
```

Like this.

```
fd = open("a", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Create a [bitmap enum](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8300/coalesce-enums-in-ida), and set arg2 to this bitfield type.

Comment: Thanks for answer me. one number possible.
like this. O_WRONLY. but O_WRONLY|O_CREAT this not possible

Comment: To change IDA's standard enum containing `O_WRONLY` etc. to the bitfield type you need to delete the harebrained `O_RDONLY` thing; otherwise IDA mumbles something like 'some constants hinder'. Then position the cursor on the enum name and hit Ctrl+N to bring up the "Edit enum type" dialogue and set a check mark next to "Bitfield". This is for plain IDA but things shouldn't be different with the Hex-Rays plugin loaded.